# Need to escape a '%' when creating a Java URL

Tags: java, url, character-encoding, uri, special-characters

I'm having trouble creating a working URL because it needs to contain some special characters.

```
String address = "...";
URL url = new URL(address);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
InputStream input = url.openStream();
....
```

The problem is that my address needs to contain a & as one of the characters in the string, expressed as %26.  When I create my address as:

```
String address = "http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious";
```

... that gets changed into

```
"http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%2526%20delicious"
```

during the URL-to-URI-and-back process.

What is the best way I should fix this?  Am I using best practices with the URL/URI conversion?  If so, is there a way to escape the '%' before the 26 so that it remains a %26 in the end?

MCVE:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String address = "http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious";
            URL url = new URL(address);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            url = uri.toURL();
            System.out.println("url: " + url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Bad!");
        }
    }

}
```

Terminal I/O:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
url: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%2520%2526%2520delicious
```

To put it another way, how do I get it to output this URL:

```
url: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious
```

Comment: I don't understand.   If you are trying to send string that has already been %-escaped in a URL, then the `%` characters >should<  be escaped.  (Alternatively, the string should have been %-escaped before you embedded it.)  Please give us a concrete example, preferably as an MCVE.

Comment: MCVE added. @StephenC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging further, I can't use this method to create the URL.  I need to use the URI constructor that takes only a single String.

I used this code to sniff out the differences and highlight the problem:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        addresses.add("http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious");
        addresses.add("http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit %26 delicious");
        addresses.add("http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit & delicious");
        //addresses.add("http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit \%26 delicious"); this uses an illegal escape character

        for (String address : addresses) {
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            try {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
                URL urlA = uri.toURL();
                System.out.println("address: " + address);
                System.out.println("yields: ");
                System.out.println("  * urlA: " + urlA);
                uri = new URI(address);
                URL urlB = uri.toURL();
                System.out.println("  * urlB: " + urlB);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("  Problem!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which produced this output in the Terminal:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
address: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious
yields: 
  * urlA: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%2520%2526%2520delicious
  * urlB: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%26%20delicious
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
address: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit %26 delicious
yields: 
  * urlA: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20%2526%20delicious
  Problem!
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
address: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit & delicious
yields: 
  * urlA: http://foo.com/?animal=monkey&banana=fruit%20&%20delicious
  Problem!
```

The result of the urlB in the first trial is the only one that works.